# Geth node sync: best metrics to track progress of state trie download?

Tags: go-ethereum, fast-sync, validators

First time setting up a full node with Geth and was hoping someone could help me better track progress.

Have been running for about 8 days and I believe geth is currently doing the "state sync"

**1) Based on the details and performance below, do you think the sync will ever complete? Or I need to change some settings / up the machine specs?**

**2) Do you have any recommendations on metrics to track the progress of the sync? I also have the InfluxDb+Grafana setup described [here](https://ethereum.org/vi/developers/tutorials/monitoring-geth-with-influxdb-and-grafana/)**

Many thanks

---

### Geth Settings

```
/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/geth --rpc --rpcaddr localhost --rpcport 8545 --datadir /ssd/ethereum --nousb --cache=8184 --syncmode fast --maxpeers 2000 --metrics --metrics.influxdb --metrics.influxdb.endpoint "http://0.0.0.0:8086" --metrics.influxdb.username "$U" --metrics.influxdb.password "$PW"
```

### Machine Specs

GCP e2-standard-2 (2 vCPUs, 8 GB memory)

500GB SSD drive

### Machine Performance

[image]

### eth.syncing output

```
{
  currentBlock: 11932371,
  highestBlock: 11932458,
  knownStates: 733106883,
  pulledStates: 733044518,
  startingBlock: 11928734
}
```

### Data Stored

```
> sudo du -H /ssd
28      /ssd/beacon/beaconchaindata
40      /ssd/beacon
179157676       /ssd/ethereum/geth/chaindata/ancient
340470580       /ssd/ethereum/geth/chaindata
201612  /ssd/ethereum/geth/ethash
4664    /ssd/ethereum/geth/nodes
709976  /ssd/ethereum/geth/triecache
341386840       /ssd/ethereum/geth
8       /ssd/ethereum/keystore
341386856       /ssd/ethereum
341386900       /ssd
```

### Latest logs sample

```
Feb 26 11:06:49 eth-node sudo[18855]: INFO [02-26|11:06:49.022] Initializing fast sync bloom             items=291095016 errorrate=0.000 elapsed=25m47.374s
Feb 26 11:06:57 eth-node sudo[18855]: INFO [02-26|11:06:57.022] Initializing fast sync bloom             items=291116651 errorrate=0.000 elapsed=25m55.375s
Feb 26 11:06:59 eth-node sudo[18855]: WARN [02-26|11:06:59.659] Dropping unsynced node during fast sync  id=9f9bb99ec1018c88 conn=inbound addr=222.190.117.130:52684 type=Geth/v1.9.25-stable-...
Feb 26 11:07:05 eth-node sudo[18855]: INFO [02-26|11:07:05.023] Initializing fast sync bloom             items=291138086 errorrate=0.000 elapsed=26m3.375s
Feb 26 11:07:06 eth-node sudo[18855]: INFO [02-26|11:07:06.240] Imported new block headers               count=1    elapsed=12.311ms    number=11932451 hash="a37c27…bf08e3" age=1m37s
Feb 26 11:07:07 eth-node sudo[18855]: INFO [02-26|11:07:07.108] Downloader queue stats                   receiptTasks=0    blockTasks=0    itemSize=201.23KiB throttle=326
Feb 26 11:07:13 eth-node sudo[18855]: INFO [02-26|11:07:13.023] Initializing fast sync bloom             items=291157306 errorrate=0.000 elapsed=26m11.375s
Feb 26 11:07:19 eth-node sudo[18855]: WARN [02-26|11:07:19.407] Checkpoint challenge timed out, dropping id=e4c869f857022b98 conn=inbound addr=47.94.10.24:42520     type=Geth/v1.9.19-stable-...
Feb 26 11:07:21 eth-node sudo[18855]: INFO [02-26|11:07:21.023] Initializing fast sync bloom             items=291177218 errorrate=0.000 elapsed=26m19.375s
Feb 26 11:07:26 eth-node sudo[18855]: INFO [02-26|11:07:26.674] Imported new state entries               count=384  elapsed="6.344µs"   processed=733043119 pending=39982 trieretry=0   coderetry=0 duplicate=0 unexpected=41
Feb 26 11:07:29 eth-node sudo[18855]: INFO [02-26|11:07:29.035] Initializing fast sync bloom             items=291194474 errorrate=0.000 elapsed=26m27.387s
Feb 26 11:07:30 eth-node sudo[18855]: WARN [02-26|11:07:30.009] Dropping unsynced node during fast sync  id=97e32697f36f3c0c conn=dyndial addr=135.181.113.114:30303 type=Geth/v1.9.6-unstable...
Feb 26 11:07:37 eth-node sudo[18855]: INFO [02-26|11:07:37.047] Initializing fast sync bloom             items=291213828 errorrate=0.000 elapsed=26m35.400s
Feb 26 11:07:45 eth-node sudo[18855]: INFO [02-26|11:07:45.048] Initializing fast sync bloom             items=291233936 errorrate=0.000 elapsed=26m43.400s
Feb 26 11:07:52 eth-node sudo[18855]: INFO [02-26|11:07:52.194] Imported new state entries               count=247  elapsed="4.277µs"   processed=733043366 pending=43934 trieretry=0   coderetry=0 duplicate=0 unexpected=41
Feb 26 11:07:53 eth-node sudo[18855]: INFO [02-26|11:07:53.049] Initializing fast sync bloom             items=291254043 errorrate=0.000 elapsed=26m51.401s
Feb 26 11:08:01 eth-node sudo[18855]: INFO [02-26|11:08:01.049] Initializing fast sync bloom             items=291277819 errorrate=0.000 elapsed=26m59.402s
Feb 26 11:08:09 eth-node sudo[18855]: INFO [02-26|11:08:09.050] Initializing fast sync bloom             items=291299359 errorrate=0.000 elapsed=27m7.402s
Feb 26 11:08:11 eth-node sudo[18855]: INFO [02-26|11:08:11.864] Imported new block headers               count=1    elapsed=15.773ms    number=11932452 hash="3aabcb…9a783b" age=2m11s
Feb 26 11:08:12 eth-node sudo[18855]: INFO [02-26|11:08:12.277] Downloader queue stats                   receiptTasks=0    blockTasks=0    itemSize=201.26KiB throttle=326
Feb 26 11:08:16 eth-node sudo[18855]: WARN [02-26|11:08:16.116] Dropping unsynced node during fast sync  id=3049cd81df1f6e5d conn=inbound addr=176.9.143.74:40158    type=Geth/v1.9.25-stable-...
Feb 26 11:08:17 eth-node sudo[18855]: INFO [02-26|11:08:17.051] Initializing fast sync bloom             items=291320239 errorrate=0.000 elapsed=27m15.403s
Feb 26 11:08:19 eth-node sudo[18855]: WARN [02-26|11:08:19.653] Dropping unsynced node during fast sync  id=309e62d9c2fa98ba conn=inbound addr=159.117.150.121:40290 type=Geth/v1.9.9-stable-0...
Feb 26 11:08:21 eth-node sudo[18855]: INFO [02-26|11:08:21.436] Imported new block headers               count=1    elapsed=37.423ms    number=11932453 hash="45e5ee…36485a" age=2m11s/v3.0.0-...
Feb 26 11:08:21 eth-node sudo[18855]: WARN [02-26|11:08:21.799] Checkpoint challenge timed out, dropping id=95069edb97397bee conn=inbound addr=18.200.194.248:45006  type=Geth/v1.9.25-stable-...
Feb 26 11:08:24 eth-node sudo[18855]: WARN [02-26|11:08:24.636] Dropping unsynced node during fast sync  id=8948548c76d25eb4 conn=dyndial addr=71.178.43.135:30302   type=Geth/v1.9.25-stable-...=0 duplicate=0 unexpected=41
Feb 26 11:08:25 eth-node sudo[18855]: INFO [02-26|11:08:25.075] Initializing fast sync bloom             items=291338275 errorrate=0.000 elapsed=27m23.427s
Feb 26 11:01:42 eth-node sudo[18855]: INFO [02-26|11:01:42.244] Imported new block headers               count=1    elapsed=12.403ms    number=11932431 hash="1ef3ce…09d21c"
Feb 26 11:01:43 eth-node sudo[18855]: INFO [02-26|11:01:43.144] Downloader queue stats                   receiptTasks=0    blockTasks=0    itemSize=215.80KiB t
```